# Display Total Number or Sum of Records That Fit A .Where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would I display the total number of Bids that were placed by a user?

So far I have this `<%= project.bids.where(:user_id => '3').sum :id %>` which calculates the sum of the id column so I am getting the wrong number. Rather than finding the sum of a column, I need to find the sum of entire records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to count the number of record in `project.bids.where(:user_id => '3')` ?

I guess `project.bids.where(:user_id => '3').count` ?